# The win10toast distribution was not found is displayed while i execute a python exe with toastnotification

Tags: python

The win10toast distribution was not found is displayed while i execute a python exe with toastnotification

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Hello World!!!",
              "Python is 10 seconds awsm!",
              icon_path="custom.ico",
              duration=10)
toaster.show_toast("Hello World!!!",
             "Python is awesome by default!")
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZdu0.png)

Comment: Try installing win10toast. If it is installed, make sure that the Python search paths are correct. Also, please provide relevant information, such as the exact error message, directly in your question, instead of an attached screenshot.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 127, in show_toast
  File "site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 93, in _show_toast
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1225, in resource_filename
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 436, in get_provider
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 984, in require

Comment: File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 870, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'win10toast' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[10128] Failed to execute script delete

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this by switching to `plyer` library. Initially, it had a similar issue but adding platform-specific import helped:

```
import plyer.platforms.win.notification
from plyer import notification

notification.notify("Title", "Body")
```

Reference:
https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/485

Answer (score 1):

Me to faced the same problem, I have imported six,appdir and packaging.requirements in my code and converted to exe using cx_Freeze now it is working for me

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import six
import appdirs
import packaging.requirements

toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast(
    "Testing pyinstaller",
    "Trying to find root cause",
    duration=10, icon_path="python.ico")
```

Note:
we can also use this packages as hidden_import in Pyinstaller but i had not yet tested yet in pyinstaller

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the icon_path argument in the second toaster. In my case, I solved this issue providing a valid icon_path. If this doesn't work, try `icon_path=''`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but with **win10toast_click** module.

I traced the following exception's call stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 123, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 116, in main
  File "main.py", line 101, in check_query
  File "main.py", line 84, in notify
  File "win10toast_click\__init__.py", line 162, in show_toast
  File "win10toast_click\__init__.py", line 127, in _show_toast
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1130, in resource_filename
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 342, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 886, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'win10toast_click' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

And I found out that in file `win10toast_click\__init__.py`, line 127, in `_show_toast` function, it's failing to retrieve the icon or something (`resource_filename` is failing at the 'else' clause):

```
        # icon
        if icon_path is not None:
            icon_path = path.realpath(icon_path)
        else:
            icon_path =  resource_filename(Requirement.parse("win10toast_click"), "win10toast_click/icon/notification.ico")
        icon_flags = LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_DEFAULTSIZE
```

So what I did is to copy the icon file from that path, and paste it into my project's main folder, then I specified the `icon_path` to that new path when calling the `show_toast` method, like this:  `toaster.show_toast(title, msg, icon_path='notification.ico')`

On my machine, the icon's original path is: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\win10toast_click\icon\notification.ico`